# how to wrap java program into single-exe-file including signed jars like bouncycastle

Tags: java, jar, exe, digital-signature

I need to package a java program (with a bundle jre) into a single exe file. Until now I always used Launch4J. Launch4j only accepts one single jar though, so I always packed all external libraries into one single jar before calling launch4j.

This doesn't work with the bouncycastle libraries, since they are signed and extracting and re-packing them into the single jar damages the signature.

Signing the resulting "onejar" doesn't help, because the bouncycastle libraries expect a trusted sign authority.

I didn't find any other recent exe wrapper besides Launch4j which accepts external jars.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is the oracle java (fx) packager tool. It took a bit to work for me, but at the end I think it is the best solution to this problem right now (2016) since it is quite new and gets updated from release to release. It's called javafxpackager, but it works for non-fx-applications as well. It can produce applications for Win, Mac and Linux.

See here for more details on the java(fx)packager:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm

A good overview over all the existing tools do deploy java applications can be found here:
http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: It is simply `javapackager` now: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem and want to explain here briefly, maybe somebody is interested:

You can instruct Launch4j not to wrap the jars into the exe, but access them in an outside folder. To do so, set `<dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>`

and provide the *runtime* path to the main class jar via
`<jar>myfolder/myjar.jar</jar>`

All other external libraries can be put in a separate library folder. (via `<classPath><cp>mylibraries</cp></classPath>`)